# R - how to convert JavaScript timestamp to human date time with as.POSIXct?

Tags: javascript, r, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How can I convert a timestamp in this format to human date?

I create the timestamp using javascript:

```
Date.now();
```

Output example:

```
1468833354929
```

Then I store it in a db.

So when I try to convert it with R:

```
date <- as.POSIXct(1468833354929, origin="1970-01-01", tz="Asia/Singapore")
```

I get:

```
48515-06-24 09:15:29 SGT
```

But it should be:

```
2016-07-18 09:15:29 SGT
```

Any ideas why and how I can get the correct human date-time?

Comment: Your expectation that it should be "2016-07-18 09:15:29 SGT" is incorrect.  The date should be 2016-07-18, but the HMS should not be the same as the output from `as.POSIXct(1468833354929, origin="1970-01-01", tz="Asia/Singapore")`.

Comment: @teelou you can also use (now <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()))  no?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich `Your expectation that it should be "2016-07-18 09:15:29 SGT" is incorrect.` - sorry i dont get it. What is `HMS` btw?

Comment: "HMS" are hours, minutes, seconds.  Your expectation is incorrect because my answer shows the HMS should be "17:15:54", not "09:15:29".

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich you are right. it should be "17:15:54". I am going to fix that. thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in milliseconds. Divide by 1000.

```
R> as.POSIXct(1468833354929/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="Asia/Singapore")
[1] "2016-07-18 17:15:54 SGT"
```

Comment: aww never thought it is that simple in R! thanks! :D